# CAS server intgration with Spring vs Spring Security native

Tags: single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, cas

We are developing a product that consists of a set of micro services developed as Spring Rest API, those APIs will be called using Angular JS client (not confidential client to server communication) and will also interact with each other (server-to-server communication );
We are in the stage of developing an SSO solution where we also want to implement authorization based on user roles for each API, while diving more through Spring Security, I have noticed the great support for OAuth2 standard, but at the same time I saw 
Implementation for a CAS server integrated with spring client;
Now my question, why would someone goes with CAS server instead of using native spring security implementation and how roles will be passed from the CAS  server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to further study the concept of centralized single sign-on and different components in the architecture. Spring Security is a client library mostly used by the app to contact a server of some sort. CAS, as a software system, is a server. Your client application can use any library you like to contact the "account source" or the "identity provider" server. The server on the other hand, depending on the capabilities of the client will respond and react according to the semantics of the authentication protocol used.

Roles or more accurately put, attributes and claims are passed to the client app once tokens/tickets are validated using the CAS protocol. Other protocols more or less provide the same concept.